# How can I extract an html tag value for specific classes using python beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have one part of code which works, and one block which doesn't. The structure of the python and html seem the same to me so I can't understand why the second has no ouput.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {"User-Agent": "Google Chrome v6.9"}
r = requests.get("https://www.oddschecker.com/horse-racing/will-rogers-downs/22:45/winner", headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.select('.bk-logo-main-90[data-bk]'):
    print(tag['data-bk'],end=",")
for tag in soup.select('.popup selTxt[data-name]'):
    print(tag['data-name'],end=",")
```

The first for loop gives me a list of 2 letter acronyms, the second should give me a list of runners in this race but there is no output. Both are trying to find any  tags of a certain class which contains a tag of another name and return the value of that tag.

Examples of the specific html I'm looking at in case the race is run already and the page is removed:

```
<a class="bk-logo-main-90 bk-logo-click" data-bk="B3" data-track="&amp;lid=BookieLogo-B3&amp;lpos=oddsTable" title="Bet365" href="javascript:void(0);">

<a class="popup selTxt" target="" title="View odds history for My Wise Cat" href="https://www.oddschecker.com/horse-racing/will-rogers-downs/22:45/winner/bet-history/my-wise-cat" data-name="My Wise Cat">
```

Comment: Have you missed a period (`.`) before `selText`?

Comment: @IainShelvington Within the html, the class name is "popup selTxt" with just a space. I tried with your suggestion and it worked, so thank you, but I don't understand why?